# Uninstall old version and install new version in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to create a installer which checks if the older version of the software is installed or not. In case yes, it will uninstall the older version and install the new version silently by keeping all the parameters of older version (Path etc.)

I am able to check the older version by following commands:

`RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\mySoftware','DisplayVersion',pVersion)`

and uninstall the older version by:

`ShellExec('', ExpandConstant(<uninstall exe path>),'/VerySILENT /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES', '', SW_Hide, ewNoWait, ErrorCode)`

but I am unable to install the new version silently.

Comment: As I mentioned in the Inno Setup discussion group: You can pass the `/silent` or `/verysilent` parameter to your installer to run it hands-free.

Comment: Please provide sample code or the link

Comment: [Setup Command Line Parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline)

Comment: Why do you have to uninstall the old version? Why not just run the latest installer to upgrade the existing setup?

Answer (score 0):

If you are *really* certain that you need to perform an uninstall of an installed version before installing, you can use [UnInsIS.dll](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/UninsIS), which provides an Inno Setup installer the ability to check if a package is installed and potentially uninstall it before proceeding with your installation. UnInsIS.dll is open-source.